# Not getting the Python Run option in PyDev perspective

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just installed PyDev to run python scripts from eclipse. I have a Java project which has a python script that I want to run. I am in PyDev perspective (did the following: Windows -> Perspective -> Open PErspective -> Other -> Pydev -> Ok). But when I right click on the python script it doesn't show me the "Python Run" option (shown in below image). How to run that script?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8PBA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the issue is that you're not configuring the project as a PyDev project... See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html for more details on how to configure a project.

As a note, you should be using the "PyDev package explorer view" and not the plain "Navigator view" (valid modules should have a different icon there so it's easy to differentiate from a file in a configured project vs file in a project that's not configured).

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had figured it out. Thanks for your answer though. :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with your interpreter settings. May be this can help:

 Go to Window\Preferences\PyDev\Interpreters\Python Interpreter

 Click Quick Auto-Config on the top menu to automatically set the interpreter

 Then you should be able to choose to run as Python Run